# Recursive Function in Excel VBA using GoTo, Characters Combinations from Array

Tags: vba, visual-studio, excel, recursion

I want to create a `recursive` function in Excel `VBA` without using `nested` Loops. I used `GoTo` to do it as I think it is very fast as compared to For loop etc. `PROBLEM:` problem is that the first Label i.e. `'a'` does not perform all `iterations` and the required combinations are not returned so. From the given array `'arr'` there should be `39 combinations` but just 14 are returned. I i try to change some lines of code the total iterations 'iNum' returns 39, but not 39 combinations (combinations starting from `'a'` are always missing). Please help, Thanks.

```
Function rec_n()
    Dim a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim aSize As Integer, iNum As Integer
    Dim myStr As String
    'Dim arr As Variant
    Dim arr(5) As String

    'arr = Array("a", "b", "c", "d")
    arr(0) = "a"
    arr(1) = "b"
    arr(2) = "c"
    'arr(3) = "d"

    aSize = 3 - 1
    'a = 0: b = 0: c = 0

a:  If a < aSize Then
        myStr = myStr & arr(a) & ", "
        a = a + 1: iNum = iNum + 1


b:      If b < aSize Then
            myStr = myStr & arr(a) & arr(b) & ", "
            b = b + 1: iNum = iNum + 1


c:          If c < aSize Then
                'On Error Resume Next
                myStr = myStr & arr(a) & arr(b) & arr(c) & ", "
                c = c + 1: iNum = iNum + 1

                GoTo c
            Else
                c = 0
                'MsgBox c
            End If
            GoTo b
        Else
            b = 0
            'MsgBox b
        End If
        GoTo a
    End If

EndFunc:
    MsgBox iNum & vbLf & myStr
    Range("a2").Value = myStr
End Function
```

**EDITED:**
The code is resulting in just these combinations:

> a, ba, bba, bbb, bb, bca, bcb, b, ca, cba, cbb, cb, cca, ccb,

where as these 39 are expected:

> a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc, aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb,
>   abc, aca, acb, acc, baa, bab, bac, bba, bbb, bbc, bca, bcb, bcc, caa,
>   cab, cac, cba, cbb, cbc, cca, ccb, ccc,

Comment: Why are you using `GoTo` for recursive functions? Unlike some older dialects of Basic, VBA can handle recursive functions directly. You don't have to simulate them. Also -- what exactly are you trying to do? It isn't clear where the number 39 comes from

Comment: I think GoTo is the fastest among all methods and Looping is the slowest one. And I require the fastest way so as to have all alphabets array combinations.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in Debug mode?

Comment: @John Coleman You can specify some fast way other than Loops if you think some, thanks.

Comment: No, Debug mode was not tried. But I just want "Recursion or GoTo" as i think these are the fastest to iterate through trillions of combinations from whole alphabets i.e. Lower and Upper etc.

Comment: Don't use GoTo's; have the function call itself with new input parameters for your recursion. You are setting yourself up for failure by using GoTos in such a complex way; they should be reserved for absolute necessities, such as error checking.

Comment: VBA isn't a tool for handling trillions of possibilities. If you want to brute force a large number of strings there is an easy way to do so with a single loop and a simple non-recursive function (one much simpler than the one I have in my answer)

Comment: @John Coleman Can you please tell how to do that brute forcing using Single-Loop Non-Recursive Function? thanks.

Comment: @asif I edited the code which I had in mind. In effect, I inlined the the function I had in mind (to convert ints to base `n` and represent them as strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a goto-free recursive approach:

```
Function StringsFrom(A As Variant, Optional maxlen As Variant) As Variant
    'returns a 0-based array of all strings of length <= maxlen
    'with elements drawn from A
    'A is assumed to be 0-based array
    'If maxlen is missing then it is taken to be the number of elements in A

    Dim strings As Variant
    Dim newstrings As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long

    If IsMissing(maxlen) Then maxlen = 1 + UBound(A)
    m = UBound(A)
    If maxlen < 1 Then Exit Function

    If maxlen = 1 Then
        'basis case -- return a copy of A - coerced to be strings if needed
        ReDim newstrings(0 To m)
        For i = 0 To m
            newstrings(i) = CStr(A(i))
        Next i
    Else
        strings = StringsFrom(A, maxlen - 1)
        n = UBound(strings)
        ReDim newstrings(0 To n + (m + 1) ^ maxlen)
        'first copy strings to newstrings:
        For i = 0 To n
            newstrings(i) = strings(i)
        Next i

        k = n + 1 'points to current index in newstrings
        'now -- load up the rest using a nested loop:
        For i = 0 To m
            For j = n + 1 - (m + 1) ^ (maxlen - 1) To n
                newstrings(k) = A(i) & strings(j)
                k = k + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
    StringsFrom = newstrings
End Function
```

For e.g. `maxlen = 4` and `A` has 5 strings it will first find all strings of length <= `maxlen - 1 = 3` and then tack on the characters to those strings of length *exactly* 3. I had to do a bit of arithmetic to get the indices just right.

Here is some testing code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double, A As Variant, B As Variant

    A = Array("a", "b", "c")
    B = StringsFrom(A)
    MsgBox Join(B, " ") & vbCrLf & 1 + UBound(B) & " strings"

    A = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
    start = Timer
    B = StringsFrom(A)
    elapsed = Timer - start
    MsgBox Round(elapsed, 2) & " seconds to process " & 1 + UBound(B) & " strings"
End Sub
```

The first test correctly gives 3 + 9 + 27 = 39 strings, and the second test gives (on my machine) the message: "0.68 seconds to process 960799 strings". When I increase `A` more I run out of memory before time is an issue.

ON EDIT: Here is a non-recursive approach. It is slower than the recursive approach but isn't subject to out of memory problems. It is based on the idea that if e.g. your letters are "abc" then you can view e.g. strings of length 4 from those letters as being numbers in base 3 ( = `Len("abc")`) so to enumerate them just count from 0 to 3^4 -1 = 80, translate each number to base 3, then use the correspondence `0 <=> "a", 1 <=> "b" etc.):

```
Sub Enumerate(letters As String, maxlen As Long, Optional display As Boolean = True)
    'letters is assumed to have no repeated characters
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long, q As Long, r As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim A As Variant

    n = Len(letters)
    ReDim A(0 To n - 1)

    For i = 1 To n
        A(i - 1) = Mid(letters, i, 1)
    Next i

    For i = 1 To maxlen
        For j = 0 To n ^ i - 1
            s = ""
            q = j
            If q = 0 Then
                s = A(0)
            Else
                Do While q > 0
                    r = q Mod n
                    q = Int(q / n)
                    s = A(r) & s
                Loop
            End If
            s = String(i - Len(s), A(0)) & s
            counter = counter + 1
            If display Then Debug.Print s
        Next j
    Next i
    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

Tested like:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim start As Double, elapsed As Double
    Enumerate "abc", 3
    start = Timer
    Enumerate "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5, False
    elapsed = Timer - start
    Debug.Print Round(elapsed, 2)
End Sub
```

output of the time part of the test: shows that it takes (on my machine) about 18 seconds to loop through all of the (over 12.3 million) strings from the lower case standard alphabet of length <= 5. Some improvements are possible, but you aren't going to be able to get the sorts of speed you would need to brute force long strings drawn from a large alphabet.

VBA is an interpreted language. I think of it as a good tool for putzing around the solar system. If you want to explore the galaxy -- use C. If you want to explore other galaxies -- hope that quantum computers can be made to work.

On Further Edit: For fun I wrote a different version of `Enumerate`. It is about 33% faster than the last version and can loop generate nearly a million strings per second (at least on my somewhat average laptop). It is still based on thinking of strings as numbers in base `n = length(letters)` but simulates adding 1 to go from 1 number to the next, with an array used to look up which character results from "adding one" to a letter:

```
Sub Enumerate2(letters As String, maxlen As Long, Optional display As Boolean = True)
    'letters is assumed to have no repeated characters
    'prints all letter combos of length <= maxlen
    'this one simulates the process of adding one to a string

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, n As Long, p As Long
    Dim carry As Boolean
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim Successor(127) As String, Z As String, digit As String

    n = Len(letters)
    For i = 1 To n - 1
        Successor(Asc(Mid(letters, i, 1))) = Mid(letters, i + 1, 1)
    Next i
    Z = Mid(letters, 1, 1) 'the "zero" of the base-n system
    Successor(Asc(Mid(letters, n, 1))) = Z

    For i = 1 To maxlen
        ReDim num(1 To i) 'used to count from 0 to n^i - 1 in base n
        For k = 1 To i
            num(k) = Z
        Next k
        For j = 0 To n ^ i - 1
            'get current s
            s = Join(num, "")
            counter = counter + 1
            'now add 1 to num
            carry = True
            p = i 'points to rightmost "digit"
            Do While p > 0 And carry
                digit = Successor(Asc(num(p)))
                If digit <> Z Then carry = False
                num(p) = digit
                p = p - 1
            Loop
            'the real code would go here:
            If display Then Debug.Print s
        Next j
    Next i
    Debug.Print counter
End Sub
```

Comment: Your answers are very very good. Can you please post another answer containing the VBScript (.vbs) version of your answers as I want to do something necessarily on command prompt as the Excel-Vba version cannot handle trillions of strings but on command prompt it is possible. Thanking in anticipation.

Comment: If you like the answers so much you can always mark it as accepted :). Since I am not really using the Excel object model the conversion to VBScript should be fairly mechanical (e.g. get rid of the explicit variable types in the `Dim` statements, tweak the code so that all arrays are 0-based, and replace lines like `Next i` by just `Next`). But -- I won't bother since it won't help you. VBA compiles to an intermediate form ( "p-code" ) which is then interpreted, but VBScript is purely interpreted and runs slower. If anything -- move to `VB.net`, but something like this almost cries out for C.